# Adding hyperlinks into xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, hyperlink

I purchased a script online that's no longer supported and I just need one last functionality to finish off my project. One detail the client needs is to have a line of text link to another page in the site.

I do not know a whole lot about xml, but I understand it doesn't support html to include hyperlinks.

This is a quiz where users must answer specific questions in order to move on to the next step. It's fed into a div by a js file, I think, but I don't understand how it works. I'm not going to post any code just yet as I'm just reaching out for some advice right now and if what I want to do is even possible.

Is there some kind of a workaround? I've Googled plenty of sites with code chunks and have done a lot of experimenting, but I mostly just break the page the xml displays on.

Thanks.

Comment: I just edit my Answer, please take note of `CDATA`

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the actual xml syntax of tags like `<a></a>`. Better replace these with other symbols like `[a][/a]`. When you output the code, simply replace `[` and `]` with `<` and `>`

You replace code before you put it into a div could look like this:

```
 xmlAsString.replace(/\[/g,"<").replace(/\]/g,">");
```

**edit:**

I totally forgot about [CDATA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).
Forget my previous answer. Just add the **`<![CDATA[...]]>`** Tag around the anchor in your XML:

**`<![CDATA[`***`<a href="https://www.your.link.com">link</a>`***`]]>`**

Comment: Thanks Nano, does xml string you mentioned go into the js file as another line of functions? Will this then output a link from the xml file if I use the proper link syntax?

Comment: By xmlAsString, i mean your xml file handled by Javascript as string before the script inserts it into your html. At this point you can manipulate the whole xml. And yes, after Javascript inserted the xml in your html, it will be recorgnized as anchor

Comment: Place this : `data = data.replace(/\[/g,"<").replace(/\]/g,">");`  after `line 55` of you js file. And replace the anchor in your xml like i said (`[a][/a]`). Then it shoud work

Comment: I think I found another line where you shoud add it... but first try it without adding it there. After `line 615`. Also if it doesnt work after adding it to both, try searching for `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post` and read the comments in your file.

Comment: Thank you. I am still not able to get it working, but I will keep playing with your examples here and see if I can figure it out. I keep breaking the question function but I am probably not placing things correctly.

Comment: I'm finding anything I try to alter in the xml document either displays a blank space where I think the link should be or stops the quiz from displaying entirely.